# Retain thread to listen delegate methods

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I detach a NSThread say "thread2" and then call the NSUrlConnection class to get an xml from the remote server. Even it is not useful but i want to do that.

Now my problem is the thread2 does wait for the delegate methods  response. I want that delegate methods should be called on that thread2 and thread wait for the response.

Is it possible or not. If yes then how.

Comment: If you detach a new thread, you need to use the synchronous method. If you don't want to use the synchronous method, you'll need to set up and pump a run loop until the connection completes in the detached selector. It's almost certainly best just to do this from the main thread where the system pumps the run loop for you, if you're using asynchronous call-backs.

Comment: how to use synchronous method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the synchronous method like so (assume you are dispatching the new thread to this method, or wrap this in a GCD call to a global queue):

```
- (void)threadDispatchMethod
{
  NSError* error = nil;
  NSData* result = nil;
  NSURLResponse* response = nil;
  result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
  if( result ) {
    // do wonderful things
  } else {
    // cry :'(
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. One last thing if u wish to answer why NSURlConnection does not response to same thread but NSXMLParser response to same thread.

Comment: if NSURLConnection is not synchronous